# SQL Query to find Employee who took max leave on Monday or Friday on this month

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, max

Can anyone help to solve this query?

```
select employee who has taken max leave on monday or friday for the current month?
```

Comment: Please show us your own attempts and explain the problem a bit clearer. For me it's a bit unclear (*who has taken max leave on monday or friday*).

Comment: please add your table and columns

Comment: @diiN_ I need to find employee name from the table where the employee took leave only monday or friday. among the employee list i need person who took maximum leave ??

Comment: Employee Table

EmpID         NUMBER, 
EmpName       NVARCHAR,
EmpAge        NUMBER, 
EmpAddress    NVARCHAR,
EmpAttendance DATE

Comment: So, your `employee` table has a column called `EmpAttendance`. Does this mean there is a record in the table for every day the employee shows up to work? And if there isn't a record then the employee is considered on leave?

Comment: EmpAttendance is the Date column.. here Employee Attendance will register

Comment: @APC  if the Column having null value means employee leave at the day

Comment: how can we understand in this month_? which date column to check it

Comment: "if the Column having null value means employee leave at the day" Eh? If the `EmpAttendance` column is null how we will know what date it's supposed to be? Either your data model is broken or there's some other column which you haven't posted. If you want people to help, you should post a *complete working example* of your code, with sample data and expected results .

Answer (score 0):

### TRY THIS

```
SELECT EMPNAME
  FROM EMPLOYEE
 WHERE EMPID =
          (
          SELECT EMPID
          FROM
              (
              SELECT EMPID,COUNT(*)
                 FROM EMPLOYEE
                WHERE     
                DATE_COL BETWEEN TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'MM') AND   TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, 1),'MM')- 1 
                AND TO_CHAR (DATE_COL, 'd') IN (1, 5)
                AND EMPATTENDANCE IS NULL
                group by EMPID
                ORDER BY 2 DESC
               ) 
           WHERE rownum = 1
           )
```

Comment: can you     explain  subquery??                                                                                                            SELECT EMPID
          FROM
              (
              SELECT EMPID,COUNT(*)
                 FROM EMPLOYEE
                WHERE     
                DATE_COL BETWEEN TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'MM') AND   TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, 1),'MM')- 1 
                AND TO_CHAR (DATE_COL, 'd') IN (1, 5)
                AND EMPATTENDANCE IS NULL
                ORDER BY 2 DESC
               ) 
           WHERE rownum = 1

Comment: I updated my answer(added group by) I found max emp which took leave on monday or friday